# gSoap - service call returns with SOAP_OK, but return struct uninitialized

Tags: c, gsoap, ansi-c

This is a *dereference of null pointer* problem - in both the ANSI C & gSoap domains:

I am using the following public [WSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language):

```
http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl
```

and have tested its behavior using soapUI.
I created client-side only ANSI C bindings using the wsdl2h and soapcpp2 utilities.

*The problem:*

In previous gsoap projects, results structures in the client soap_call functions (the fifth argument) required no initialization other than something like:

```
struct ns2__countryInfoByIanaResponse out, *pOut
pOut= &out;
```

this has always been sufficient until this project.
The client soap_call looks like this:

```
soap_call_ns2__countryInfoByIana(&soap, NULL, NULL, pIn, pOut); /* SOAP 1.2 RPC return element...*/
```

`pIn` for this project is defined as a `char *`, populated with a two character [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) code such as "us", or "nz".  The return structure `pOut` for this particular call is shaped like this:

```
struct ns2__countryInfoByIanaResponse
{
    struct ns1__CountryData *countryinfo;
}
```

With `ns1__CountryData` shaped like this:

```
struct ns1__CountryData
{
    char *ianacode; /* required element of type xsd:string */
    char *countryname;  /* required element of type xsd:string */
    float latitude; /* required element of type xsd:float */
    float longitude;    /* required element of type xsd:float */
};
```

A call to this function from my application is therefore set up like this:

```
//declare response structure:
struct ns2__countryInfoByIanaResponse o, *pO;

void main(void)
{
   pO = &o;
   if(GetCountryInfo(buf, pO)==0)
   {
      pO->countryinfo->countryname; //Error Occurs Here...
   }                                
}
```

The error occurs at `pO->countryinfo` as a *dereference of null pointer*

GetCountryInfo is defined here:

```
int DLL_EXPORT GetCountryInfo(char *pIn, struct ns2__countryInfoByIanaResponse *pOut)
{

    int status = 0;
    size_t len=2048;
    char buf[2048];

    if (soap_call_ns2__countryInfoByIana(&soap, NULL, NULL, pIn, pOut)== SOAP_OK)
    {
        status = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
        soap_sprint_fault(&soap, buf, len);
        MessagePopup("soap error", buf);
        status = 1;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Other `gSoap` projects using similar output structure shapes (i.e. structures containing structures containing char *) returned fully populated results when initialized with nothing other than what I have shown above.

Any ideas?  Please let me know if I can provide any further details.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the soap server has a bug. An example soap response from the countryInfoByIana function looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:countryInfoByIanaResponse>
      <return>
        <ianacode xsi:type="xsd:string">nz</ianacode>
        <countryname xsi:type="xsd:string">New Zealand</countryname>
        <latitude xsi:type="xsd:float">-40.900558</latitude>
        <longitude xsi:type="xsd:float">174.885971</longitude>
      </return>
    </SOAP-ENV:countryInfoByIanaResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

`<SOAP-ENV:countryInfoByIanaResponse>` should have a different namespace.

Here is a part of the WSDL, which contains the same (invalid) namespace.

```
<operation name="countryInfoByIana">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/#Countries#countryInfoByIana" />
  <input>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
  </output>
</operation>
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding your question why soapUI works fine;  soapUI probably does not validate the return value the same way gsoap is doing.

I managed to let the program succeed on my pc using gsoap 2.7:

In soapClient.c line 56, change this line:

```
//soap_get_ns2__countryInfoByIanaResponse(soap, _param_1, "ns2:countryInfoByIanaResponse", "");
soap_get_ns2__countryInfoByIanaResponse(soap, _param_1, "SOAP-ENV:countryInfoByIanaResponse", "");
```

In soapC.c line 1470, change this line:

```
//if (soap_in_PointerTons1__CountryData(soap, "countryinfo", &a->countryinfo, "ns1:CountryData"))
if (soap_in_PointerTons1__CountryData(soap, "return", &a->countryinfo, "ns1:CountryData"))//return
```

But I don't think you should solve problems this way. Not only because both files are generated, so you will lose your changes when you generate it again.

Comment: 2 Questions: 1) when I use this WSDL within soapUI, it consistently returns data.  Does the server then respond differently with queries from a utility like soapUI as opposed to gsoap generated c bindings?  2)In your experience, is there something possibly in my gsoap generated code that can be edited to cause its query and response to more resemble those generated with soapUI?  Thanks, Ryyker

Comment: btw, you can use a tool like wireshark to see if gsoap and soapUI send the same data, and what the difference is.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications above, and for the wireshark tip.  I will try both.  And regarding your comment about modifying generated code, I agree, but do not see any way around it if I need to use the service with gSoap source code.  As a work around when I have to make edits, I use in-line comments and changed filenames to explain changes, and to protect modified files.  Again, thanks for your help, Ryyker